# window.location.href doesn't work in typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, typescript

I'm trying to add logout in my application. so I call get /logout webservice and I have as response an url. Then I use this url to redirect my page to returned url.

Here is my code:

```
 constructor(
$q: ng.IQService,
$location: ng.ILocationService,
$window: ng.IWindowService,
$http: ng.IHttpService
) {
this._$q = $q;
this._$location = $location;
this._$window = $window;

this.logout = () => {
  return $http
    .get(logoutUri, {})
    .success((resp:any): void  => {
      window.location.href = resp;
    });
};
}
```

In resp, I get the correct url but my page is not redirected to the specific url.

Comment: If you insert a `console.log(resp)` call directly before setting `window.location.href`, what gets written to the dev console?

Comment: it writen the correct url. I tryed also with window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'; and it's doesn't work

Comment: Then I'll pass. I don't (yet) know AngularJS in depth, but I assume there's a function dedicated for redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of;

`window.location.href = resp`

try

```
$location.path(resp);
$location.replace();
```